# AngularJS: JSON array from Filter

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

i have a quick question. I have a filter where i pass an array and get back an Array:

The Filter returns a JSON Array generated by underscore.js library:

```
myApp.filter('theFilter', function () {
        return function(items){
            return _.countBy(items, function(num) {
              return num % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
            });
        };
});
```

this `{{array | theFilter }}` outputs only a json array like this: {{ "even":3, "odd":5 }}

How can i output the value of even for example?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Can you provide a plunker??

Comment: Here is a plunkr [http://plnkr.co/edit/z3ppJZAZFmyXJqnUKmSN?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/z3ppJZAZFmyXJqnUKmSN?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried, it works perfectly

```
{{(items | theFilter).even}}
```

[worked plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dUye6wyjsPiLbKmfd95O?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.filter('theFilter', function () {
    return function(items){
        return _.countBy(items, function(num) {
          return num % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
        }).even;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need write another filter:

```
myApp.filter('theFilter', function () {
        return function(items){
            return _.countBy(items, function(num) {
              return num % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
            });
        };
});

myApp.filter('attr', function () {
        return function(obj, attrName){
            return obj ? obj[attrName] : undefined;
        };
});

{{array | theFilter | attr:'even'}}
```

Comment: @MarcoStandzettel http://plnkr.co/edit/oNK3v7CHhOKlXvXXZYju?p=preview you can have a try

Comment: But I think the solution of @huan-feng is better :)